# New 52: Is it common knowledge that Nightwing was Robin?

Tags: dc, robin, nightwing

In what passes for the current DC Comics continuity, is there any indication of how widespread the knowledge is of Nightwing being a former Robin?

[image]

Comment: This question needs Thaddeus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current continuity, it appears to be thoroughly common knowledge. Witness the following "Chirper" (DC brand-X Twitter) exchange from 2017's *Nightwing* #16:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most continuities it seems to be an open secret among criminals who recognize him by banter or the fact that Batman is hanging out with a new guy who has the same build, voice and hair Robin had. He usually changes while in the Teen Titans which are a team in the public eye and the public notices the new guy on the Titans has the same build,voice and hair as Robin. I don't know of any stories or panels where he will deny the Robin connection if anyone asks him.